# WPF - Pop a Loading window when busy

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have to show a Window on an application that is not very well thought. The calls from every window are made from the same thread, no background workers. The application is rather yuge, so I can't just go around implementing BW pattern. Problem is, some of those actions take a while (around 5-10 seconds) and the whole app would turn Not Responding while waiting.

My idea was to implement some kind of watchdog on a background thread that would pop a window whenever I set a flag (App.Loading) in order to let the user know that something is going on.

In order to do that, I put this in the main menu

```
        public Menu()
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            Debug.Ventana = "Menu";
            App.Menu = this;

            Loading = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckLoading));
            Loading.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            Loading.Start();
        }

        private void CheckLoading()
        {
            Loading load = new Andrei.Loading("Cargando datos")
            {
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                Topmost = true
            };
            while(true)
            {
                if (App.Loading && !load.IsVisible)
                    load.Show();
                if (!App.Loading && load.IsVisible)
                    load.Hide();
            }
        }
```

Problem is, sometimes the window does not show up, and when it does, the animation isn't working (it's a small window with a string and an Indeterminate Progress Bar), which must be because the main thread is frozen by the while(true). I've tried putting the loop in yet another thread, but I can't access the window from another thread to hide and show it. I've tried putting a BW on the window to check for progress, but of course, after completing the first cycle, it doesn't go looking for the flag anymore.

Any other suggestions than completely redesigning the application to use BW for any and all time-taking processes?

Comment: If main thread is being heavily loaded - creating new threads with popups won't help. You must move all the heavy actions from main thread to background worker - and then inform with popup, that action is undergoing

Comment: I agree with Piotr. Plus, why not firing an event instead of a forever loop?

Comment: @Piotr Well, I don't go around moving all actions to BW mainly because we're talking of around 100 classes, and they're pressuring me too hard to be able to do that in a timely manner. They asked me to "just display a loading bar while the app is doing something".

Comment: I don't know any other way to do it properly. You have heavy operations on the main thread - and not much more can be done. Think of it like it would be a train going with great speed. There is a man there who must put coal to keep up the "fuel level" And now you want to run a new train (side by side) and you are saying - "hey poor guy. If it happens, that you have too much work - give me a sign and I will inform everyone else, that you have much work. What would such guy tell you? That you are insane, and he hasn't got time to let you know:)"

Comment: I understand what you mean, however, in my case, the guy DOES tell me that he's got a lot of work, I'm just not able to do anything with that information atm...I'll try to convince my manager we need a full redesign. Wish me luck